# python MySQLdb query tables iteratively

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm trying to query one table against the other using Python and MySQLdb. Here's what I've got so far:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect( host = 'localhost', user = 'user', passwd= 
'password', db = 'vacants')

cursor = db.cursor()

numrows = cursor.rowcount

query = "SELECT address, ((20903520) * acos (cos ( radians(38.67054) )* cos( 
radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( `long` ) - radians(-90.22942) ) + sin ( 
radians(38.67054) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ))) AS distance FROM vacants HAVING 
distance < 100;"

cursor.execute(query)
```

I have one table, cfs, and another, vacants. I want to see for each row in cfs is there a vacant property within 100 feet. So for the ( radians(38.67054) and radians(-90.22942), I need to loop through the cfs table so that each cfs latitude and longitude replaces those two numbers. (That's just a test latitude and longitude we used)

In the end I'd like to have (in a .csv) the vacant property address, the distance from the call for service, and the type of call (which are two separate fields in the calls for service database). Something like this, which is from the query above:

[image]

Here's example data - calls for service coordinates:

```
38.595767638008056,-90.2316138251402
38.57283495467307,-90.24649031378685
38.67497061776659,-90.28415976525395
38.67650431524285,-90.25623757427952
38.591971519414784,-90.27782710145746
38.61272746420862,-90.23292862245287
38.67312983860098,-90.23591869583113
38.625956494342674,-90.18853950906939
38.69044465638584,-90.24339061920696
38.67745024638241,-90.20657832034047
```

And vacants:

```
38.67054,-90.22942
38.642956,-90.21466
38.671535,-90.27293
38.666367,-90.23749
38.65339,-90.23141
38.645996,-90.20334
38.60214,-90.224815
38.67265,-90.214134
38.665504,-90.274414
38.668354,-90.269966
```

Comment: Is there a field missing from vacants, should this also contain the address - "xxxx FARLAN AV"?

Comment: Should what contain the address? What's the "this" you're referencing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the final solution as there is insufficient info (address field? and 20903520 ?) in  the question but it might help you get on track by showing how to iterate through both tables and substitute lat, lon from the CFS table into the query applied to the vacants table:

```
import mysql.connector
cnx1 = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='xxxx',host='127.0.0.1',database=db)
cursor1 = cnx1.cursor()
cnx2 = mysql.connector.connect(user='root',password='xxxx',host='127.0.0.1',database=db)
cursor2 = cnx2.cursor()

sql_cfs = ('select lat,lon from cfs')

cursor1.execute(sql_cfs)
for cfs in cursor1:
    [cfs_lat,cfs_lon] = cfs
    print (cfs_lat,cfs_lon)
    query = ("SELECT address, ((20903520) * " \
        "acos (cos(radians(lon)) *" \
        "cos(radians({})) * " \
        "cos(radians({})-radians(lat)) + sin(radians(lon)) * " \
        "sin( radians({})))) AS distance " \
        "FROM vacants HAVING distance < 100;".format(cfs_lat,cfs_lon,cfs_lat))

    print (query)

    cursor2.execute(query)
    for vacants in cursor2:
        print (vacants)
```

Comment: It should be vacants.address (vacants is the name of the db as well as the name of a table in the db) and 20903520 comes from multiplying 3959 by 5280 so that we can check a 100-foot boundary (not miles)

Comment: What fields are in the vacants table (desc vacants;)?